# How to have a deadlock scenario with boost MPI (I use MPICH compiler)?

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, boost-mpi

I am trying to find out in what cases a potentially blocking boost mpi "send" will actually block and causes a deadlock.

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  boost::mpi::environment env{argc, argv};
  boost::mpi::communicator world;
  if (world.rank() == 0)
  {
    char buffer[14];
    const char *c = "Hello, world from 1!";
    world.send(1, 1, c, 13);
    std::cout << "1--11111\n";
    world.send(1, 1, c, 13);
    std::cout << "1--22222\n";
    world.recv(1, 1, buffer, 13);
    std::cout << "1--33333\n";
    world.recv(1, 1, buffer, 13);
    std::cout << "1--44444\n";
     buffer[13] = '\0';
    std::cout << buffer << "11 \n";
  }
  else
  {
    char buffer[14];
    const char *c = "Hello, world from 2!";
    world.send(0, 1, c, 13);
    std::cout << "2--11111\n";
    world.send(0, 1, c, 13);
    std::cout << "2--22222\n";
    world.recv(0, 1, buffer, 13);
    std::cout << "2--33333\n";
    world.recv(0, 1, buffer, 13);
    std::cout << "2--44444\n";
    buffer[13] = '\0';
    std::cout << buffer << "22 \n";
  }
}
```

but it runs just fine and the with this order:

```
2--11111
2--22222
1--11111
1--22222
1--33333
1--44444
Hello, world 11 
2--33333
2--44444
Hello, world 22
```

I will be grateful if someone could give me a scenario in which I have actually deadlock. 
How does the potentially blocking boost mpi works?

Thank you.

Comment: Boost is not an MPI implementation, it's just an interface wrapper to make it fit in better with C++. You want to be asking about specific MPI implementations, such as MPICH, OpenMPI, MVAPICH, Intel MPI, Cray, IBM, SGI, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementations may or may not complete `MPI_Send` before the recieve is posted. Your code is not a correct MPI application. It may deadlock with a specific message size, on a specific network, during full moon while it's raining.

In practice it mostly depends on the message size as implementations commonly send small messages to preallocated buffers. There may be a tuning parameter depending on your implementation.

MPI describes several communication modes. The default is **blocking**<sup>1</sup> or **standard** mode, as described above. A **synchronous** send (`MPI_Ssend`) must wait for the receive to be posted. This will guarantee a deadlock.

A **buffered** send (`MPI_Bsend`) must complete even if the recieve is not posted. In addition to the modes, there are **nonblocking** or **immediate** calls that will always complete locally, but may not copy the data yet. Both will guarantee no deadlock. However only the latter is supported by boost.MPI.

1: **blocking** in the terminology only means that the call blocks until the send buffer can be reused. Either because it was sent, or because it was buffered locally. Also take a look at [the standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node47.htm#Node47).

Answer (score 1):

The generally easiest way to force blocking behavior is to use larger messages that cause a switch to a so-called 'rendezvous' protocol, where the sender will wait for the recipient to post the matching receive operation before starting data transfer.

Comment: It does whatever the MPI library thinks will be most efficient. If the program is structured in a way that `MPI_Send` blocking can cause a deadlock, then that's a bug that should be fixed.